QuickFix.UnsupportedVersion: Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4) while receiving MarketDataIncrementalRefresh
I'm working on managing a market data stream using the FIX Protocol with QuickFIXn (version 1.12.0) on a Windows machine, specifically using FIX 4.4. After successfully connecting to the server, I receive a market data message (MsgType X), but it results in the following error:
**\<event\> QuickFix.UnsupportedVersion: Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)
at QuickFix.DefaultMessageFactory.Create(String beginString, String msgType, Int32 groupCounterTag)
at QuickFix.Message.SetGroup(StringField grpNoFld, String msgstr, Int32 pos, FieldMap fieldMap, IGroupSpec groupSpec, IMessageFactory msgFactory)
at QuickFix.Message.FromString(String msgstr, Boolean validate, DataDictionary transportDict, DataDictionary appDict, IMessageFactory msgFactory, Boolean ignoreBody)
at QuickFix.MessageBuilder.Build()
at QuickFix.Session.Next(MessageBuilder msgBuilder)**


I'm doubtful this issue is related to my overall configuration since the connection to the server works properly. This error only occurs when subscribing to market data. There are no indications of missing tags or any rejection messages that would trigger a logout or session termination.
My sender headers:
<fix major="4" minor="4">
    <header>
        <field name="BeginString" required="Y"/>
        <field name="BodyLength" required="Y"/>
        <field name="MsgType" required="Y"/>
        <field name="SenderCompID" required="Y"/>
        <field name="SenderSubID" required="N"/>
        <field name="TargetCompID" required="Y"/>
        <field name="MsgSeqNum" required="Y"/>
        <field name="PossDupFlag" required="N"/>
        <field name="SendingTime" required="Y"/>
        <field name="OrigSendingTime" required="N"/>
    </header>


I've seen there was similar problem but it referring linux machine and it was fixed with PR:
Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4) in c# (Quickfixn)
8=FIX.4.49=8035=A34=149=XXXXXXMD52=20241002-14:16:00.92556=XXXXXXX98=0108=60141=Y10=205
8=FIX.4.49=8035=A34=149=XXXXXXOR52=20241002-14:16:00.92856=XXXXXXX98=0108=60141=Y10=224
<event> Session reset: ResetSeqNumFlag
<event> Session reset: ResetSeqNumFlag
<outgoing> 8=FIX.4.4|9=80|35=A|34=1|49=XXXXXXMD|52=20241002-14:16:00.925|56=XXXXXXX|98=0|108=60|141=Y|10=205|
<outgoing> 8=FIX.4.4|9=80|35=A|34=1|49=XXXXXXOR|52=20241002-14:16:00.928|56=XXXXXXX|98=0|108=60|141=Y|10=224|
<event> Initiated logon request
<event> Initiated logon request
<incoming> 8=FIX.4.4|9=77|35=A|34=1|49=XXXXXXX|52=20241002-14:16:01.131853|56=XXXXXXOR|98=0|108=60|10=076|
<incoming> 8=FIX.4.4|9=77|35=A|34=1|49=XXXXXXX|52=20241002-14:16:01.131723|56=XXXXXXMD|98=0|108=60|10=056|
8=FIX.4.49=7735=A34=149=XXXXXXX52=20241002-14:16:01.13172356=XXXXXXMD98=0108=6010=056
8=FIX.4.49=7735=A34=149=XXXXXXX52=20241002-14:16:01.13185356=XXXXXXOR98=0108=6010=076
<outgoing> 8=FIX.4.4|9=164|35=V|34=2|49=XXXXXXMD|52=20241002-14:16:06.643|56=XXXXXXX|262=2024100214160600|263=1|264=0|265=1|146=1|55=NQ100|200=DEC24|461=FXXXXX|267=2|269=0|269=1|10=065|
<incoming> 8=FIX.4.4|9=53898|35=W|34=2|49=XXXXXXX|52=20241002-14:16:06.808028|56=XXXXXXMD|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|262=2024100214160600|268=1632|269=0|
270=19949.25|271=3|290=1|269=0|270=19949.00|271=5|290=2|269=0|270=19948.75|271=4|290=3|269=0|270=19948.50|271=4|290=4|269=0|270=19948.25|271=4|290=5|269=0|270=19948.00|
271=6|290=6|269=0|270=19947.75|271=2|290=7|269=0|270=19947.50|271=4|290=8|269=0|......
8=FIX.4.49=9735=534=349=XXXXXXMD52=20241002-14:16:07.56256=XXXXXXX58=Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)10=114
<outgoing> 8=FIX.4.4|9=97|35=5|34=3|49=XXXXXXMD|52=20241002-14:16:07.562|56=XXXXXXX|58=Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)|10=114|
<incoming> 8=FIX.4.4|9=121|35=f|34=3|49=XXXXXXX|52=20241002-14:16:06.808865|56=XXXXXXMD|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|326=17|461=FXXXXX|10=226|
8=FIX.4.49=12135=f34=349=XXXXXXX52=20241002-14:16:06.80886556=XXXXXXMD55=NQ100200=202412207=TQS326=17461=FXXXXX10=226
<incoming> 8=FIX.4.4|9=417|35=X|34=4|49=XXXXXXX|52=20241002-14:16:06.949673|56=XXXXXXMD|262=2024100214160600|268=4|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=0|270=19949.00|271=2|290=2|461=FXXXXX|279=2|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=0|290=1|461=FXXXXX|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=1|270=19950.00|271=2|290=1|461=FXXXXX|279=0|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=1|270=19949.75|271=2|290=1|461=FXXXXX|10=053|
<event> QuickFix.UnsupportedVersion: Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)
   at QuickFix.DefaultMessageFactory.Create(String beginString, String msgType, Int32 groupCounterTag)
   at QuickFix.Message.SetGroup(StringField grpNoFld, String msgstr, Int32 pos, FieldMap fieldMap, IGroupSpec groupSpec, IMessageFactory msgFactory)
   at QuickFix.Message.FromString(String msgstr, Boolean validate, DataDictionary transportDict, DataDictionary appDict, IMessageFactory msgFactory, Boolean ignoreBody)
   at QuickFix.MessageBuilder.Build()
   at QuickFix.Session.Next(MessageBuilder msgBuilder)
8=FIX.4.49=9735=534=449=XXXXXXMD52=20241002-14:16:07.57556=XXXXXXX58=Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)10=119
<outgoing> 8=FIX.4.4|9=97|35=5|34=4|49=XXXXXXMD|52=20241002-14:16:07.575|56=XXXXXXX|58=Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)|10=119|
<incoming> 8=FIX.4.4|9=281|35=X|34=5|49=XXXXXXX|52=20241002-14:16:06.949752|56=XXXXXXMD|262=2024100214160600|268=2|279=0|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=2|270=19949.25|271=1|272=20241002|273=14:16:06.842|461=FXXXXX|5797=2|279=0|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=B|271=189188|461=FXXXXX|10=177|
<event> QuickFix.UnsupportedVersion: Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)
   at QuickFix.DefaultMessageFactory.Create(String beginString, String msgType, Int32 groupCounterTag)
   at QuickFix.Message.SetGroup(StringField grpNoFld, String msgstr, Int32 pos, FieldMap fieldMap, IGroupSpec groupSpec, IMessageFactory msgFactory)
   at QuickFix.Message.FromString(String msgstr, Boolean validate, DataDictionary transportDict, DataDictionary appDict, IMessageFactory msgFactory, Boolean ignoreBody)
   at QuickFix.MessageBuilder.Build()
   at QuickFix.Session.Next(MessageBuilder msgBuilder)
8=FIX.4.49=9735=534=549=XXXXXXMD52=20241002-14:16:07.57956=XXXXXXX58=Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)10=124
<outgoing> 8=FIX.4.4|9=97|35=5|34=5|49=XXXXXXMD|52=20241002-14:16:07.579|56=XXXXXXX|58=Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)|10=124|
<incoming> 8=FIX.4.4|9=281|35=X|34=6|49=XXXXXXX|52=20241002-14:16:06.949802|56=XXXXXXMD|262=2024100214160600|268=2|279=0|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=2|270=19949.25|271=1|272=20241002|273=14:16:06.842|461=FXXXXX|5797=2|279=0|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=B|271=189189|461=FXXXXX|10=175|
<event> QuickFix.UnsupportedVersion: Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)
   at QuickFix.DefaultMessageFactory.Create(String beginString, String msgType, Int32 groupCounterTag)
   at QuickFix.Message.SetGroup(StringField grpNoFld, String msgstr, Int32 pos, FieldMap fieldMap, IGroupSpec groupSpec, IMessageFactory msgFactory)
   at QuickFix.Message.FromString(String msgstr, Boolean validate, DataDictionary transportDict, DataDictionary appDict, IMessageFactory msgFactory, Boolean ignoreBody)
   at QuickFix.MessageBuilder.Build()
   at QuickFix.Session.Next(MessageBuilder msgBuilder)
8=FIX.4.49=9735=534=649=XXXXXXMD52=20241002-14:16:07.58656=XXXXXXX58=Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)10=123
<outgoing> 8=FIX.4.4|9=97|35=5|34=6|49=XXXXXXMD|52=20241002-14:16:07.586|56=XXXXXXX|58=Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)|10=123|
<incoming> 8=FIX.4.4|9=1749|35=X|34=7|49=XXXXXXX|52=20241002-14:16:06.953288|56=XXXXXXMD|262=2024100214160600|268=19|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=0|270=19873.00|271=2|290=300|461=FXXXXX|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=0|270=19873.25|271=1|290=299|461=FXXXXX|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=0|270=19917.25|271=4|290=128|461=FXXXXX|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=0|270=19942.25|271=6|290=28|461=FXXXXX|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=0|270=19948.00|271=6|290=5|461=FXXXXX|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=0|270=19948.75|271=3|290=2|461=FXXXXX|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=0|270=19949.00|271=2|290=1|461=FXXXXX|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=1|270=19982.00|271=4|290=130|461=FXXXXX|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=1|270=19964.25|271=5|290=59|461=FXXXXX|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=1|270=19963.50|271=25|290=56|461=FXXXXX|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=1|270=19958.25|271=11|290=35|461=FXXXXX|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=1|270=19957.00|271=7|290=30|461=FXXXXX|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=1|270=19956.25|271=6|290=27|461=FXXXXX|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=1|270=19956.00|271=18|290=26|461=FXXXXX|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=1|270=19955.00|271=11|290=22|461=FXXXXX|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=1|270=19952.50|271=12|290=12|461=FXXXXX|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=1|270=19950.25|271=3|290=3|461=FXXXXX|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=1|270=19950.00|271=6|290=2|461=FXXXXX|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=1|270=19949.75|271=2|290=1|461=FXXXXX|10=196|
<event> QuickFix.UnsupportedVersion: Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)
   at QuickFix.DefaultMessageFactory.Create(String beginString, String msgType, Int32 groupCounterTag)
   at QuickFix.Message.SetGroup(StringField grpNoFld, String msgstr, Int32 pos, FieldMap fieldMap, IGroupSpec groupSpec, IMessageFactory msgFactory)
   at QuickFix.Message.FromString(String msgstr, Boolean validate, DataDictionary transportDict, DataDictionary appDict, IMessageFactory msgFactory, Boolean ignoreBody)
   at QuickFix.MessageBuilder.Build()
   at QuickFix.Session.Next(MessageBuilder msgBuilder)
8=FIX.4.49=9735=534=749=XXXXXXMD52=20241002-14:16:07.61456=XXXXXXX58=Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)10=116
<outgoing> 8=FIX.4.4|9=97|35=5|34=7|49=XXXXXXMD|52=20241002-14:16:07.614|56=XXXXXXX|58=Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)|10=116|
<incoming> 8=FIX.4.4|9=417|35=X|34=8|49=XXXXXXX|52=20241002-14:16:07.036195|56=XXXXXXMD|262=2024100214160600|268=4|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=0|270=19949.00|271=2|290=1|461=FXXXXX|279=0|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=0|270=19949.25|271=2|290=1|461=FXXXXX|279=1|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=1|270=19950.00|271=3|290=2|461=FXXXXX|279=2|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=1|290=1|461=FXXXXX|10=040|
<event> QuickFix.UnsupportedVersion: Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)
   at QuickFix.DefaultMessageFactory.Create(String beginString, String msgType, Int32 groupCounterTag)
   at QuickFix.Message.SetGroup(StringField grpNoFld, String msgstr, Int32 pos, FieldMap fieldMap, IGroupSpec groupSpec, IMessageFactory msgFactory)
   at QuickFix.Message.FromString(String msgstr, Boolean validate, DataDictionary transportDict, DataDictionary appDict, IMessageFactory msgFactory, Boolean ignoreBody)
   at QuickFix.MessageBuilder.Build()
   at QuickFix.Session.Next(MessageBuilder msgBuilder)
8=FIX.4.49=9735=534=849=XXXXXXMD52=20241002-14:16:07.65956=XXXXXXX58=Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)10=126
<outgoing> 8=FIX.4.4|9=97|35=5|34=8|49=XXXXXXMD|52=20241002-14:16:07.659|56=XXXXXXX|58=Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)|10=126|
<incoming> 8=FIX.4.4|9=281|35=X|34=9|49=XXXXXXX|52=20241002-14:16:07.036272|56=XXXXXXMD|262=2024100214160600|268=2|279=0|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=2|270=19949.00|271=1|272=20241002|273=14:16:06.861|461=FXXXXX|5797=2|279=0|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=B|271=189190|461=FXXXXX|10=153|
<event> QuickFix.UnsupportedVersion: Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)
   at QuickFix.DefaultMessageFactory.Create(String beginString, String msgType, Int32 groupCounterTag)
   at QuickFix.Message.SetGroup(StringField grpNoFld, String msgstr, Int32 pos, FieldMap fieldMap, IGroupSpec groupSpec, IMessageFactory msgFactory)
   at QuickFix.Message.FromString(String msgstr, Boolean validate, DataDictionary transportDict, DataDictionary appDict, IMessageFactory msgFactory, Boolean ignoreBody)
   at QuickFix.MessageBuilder.Build()
   at QuickFix.Session.Next(MessageBuilder msgBuilder)
8=FIX.4.49=9735=534=949=XXXXXXMD52=20241002-14:16:07.66456=XXXXXXX58=Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)10=123
<outgoing> 8=FIX.4.4|9=97|35=5|34=9|49=XXXXXXMD|52=20241002-14:16:07.664|56=XXXXXXX|58=Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)|10=123|
<incoming> 8=FIX.4.4|9=282|35=X|34=10|49=XXXXXXX|52=20241002-14:16:07.036324|56=XXXXXXMD|262=2024100214160600|268=2|279=0|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=2|270=19949.75|271=1|272=20241002|273=14:16:06.890|461=FXXXXX|5797=1|279=0|55=NQ100|200=202412|207=TQS|269=B|271=189191|461=FXXXXX|10=206|
<event> QuickFix.UnsupportedVersion: Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)
   at QuickFix.DefaultMessageFactory.Create(String beginString, String msgType, Int32 groupCounterTag)
   at QuickFix.Message.SetGroup(StringField grpNoFld, String msgstr, Int32 pos, FieldMap fieldMap, IGroupSpec groupSpec, IMessageFactory msgFactory)
   at QuickFix.Message.FromString(String msgstr, Boolean validate, DataDictionary transportDict, DataDictionary appDict, IMessageFactory msgFactory, Boolean ignoreBody)
   at QuickFix.MessageBuilder.Build()
   at QuickFix.Session.Next(MessageBuilder msgBuilder)
8=FIX.4.49=9835=534=1049=XXXXXXMD52=20241002-14:16:07.67056=XXXXXXX58=Incorrect BeginString (FIX.4.4)10=161


(1) Does this happen consistently every time you receive a 35=X message?  (2) Is your app making multiple FIX connections in the same program?  (3) Can I see a message log excerpt with a 35=X in it (and a few messages before it)?

@GrantBirchmeier I've updated question with logs

Yes, also before message X there always comes a response with MarketDataSnapshot(W)
There is also second connection for orders


I am the lead of QF/n, and I really want to solve this.  Can you open an issue on github.com/connamara/quickfixn and we can continue there?  Please change your app to use a FileLogFactory and post the separate message & event logs for the XXXXXXMD session only.

I've opened a new issue with details here
https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/issues/894
